# Can we construct a Koch curve with similarity dimension $s\in[1,2]$?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, fractals, curves

We can make a Koch curve $K$ with similarity dimension $s\in \mathbb Q \cap [1,2]$ by writing $s=\frac{p}{q}$, and constructing such a generator that by scaling with the factor of $2^q$, we'd find $2^p$ of it inside the scaled one. Then

$$\dim_\text{similarity}K=\log_{2^q}2^p=\frac{p}{q}=s.$$

Example: a generator of a Koch curve with $s=\frac{3}{2}$:

[image]

Obviously, the procedure needs $s$ to be rational.

Is there a way to construct a Koch curve for any real $s\in[1,2]$?

Comment: If I make a curve, how do I know if it's "a Koch curve" or not? What is the definition of "a Koch curve"?

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: I guess, it's more of a convention to call curves with this type of construction Koch curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to construct a "Koch-like curve" of any dimension $s$ in the open interval $1<s<2$. We simply generate a self-similar set based on the iterative scheme implied by the following picture.

[image]

Note that $r$ is parameter satisfying $1/4<r<1/2$.  The resulting fractal has dimension
$$\log(4)/\log(1/r).$$
When $r=1/4$, the result is an interval with dimension $1$, when $r=1/2$, the result is a solid triangle with dimension $2$, and any dimension between these is obtained as $r$ ranges from $1/4$ to $1/2$.  We can illustrate this evolution as follows:

[image]

Depending on your meaning of "Koch-like curve", you might say that we've already hit the values $1$ and $2$.  There is also a notion of borderline fractal that might be more "Koch-like" but is not strictly self-similar.  I might be able to elaborate on that, if there is interest.

Comment: http://fractalcurves.com/familytree/images/1.10.jpg from http://fractalcurves.com/familytree/ Figure 1,10 shows one curve with dimension changing along it, complementing your animation

Comment: @Claude Thanks for the interesting link!